# Why Marzipano is not showing the image on mobile devices (browsers)

Tags: javascript, laravel, web

I am using [Marzipano](http://www.marzipano.net/) to display 360-grade images of specific places on my website. It is working fine on desktop and laptop devices (browsers) but not on mobile. Below is the code:

```
// Create viewer
var viewer = new Marzipano.Viewer(document.getElementById('pano'));

// Create a source
var source = Marzipano.ImageUrlSource.fromString("{{asset('images/panorama/'.$business->panorama) }}");

// Create geometry.
var geometry = new Marzipano.EquirectGeometry([{ width: 4000 }]);

// Create view.
var limiter = Marzipano.RectilinearView.limit.traditional(1024, 100*Math.PI/180);

var view = new Marzipano.RectilinearView({ yaw: Math.PI }, limiter);

// Create scene.
var scene = viewer.createScene({
    source: source,
    geometry: geometry,
    view: view,
    pinFirstLevel: true
});

// Display scene.
scene.switchTo();
```

Is it any kind of image size restrictions on mobile browsers or what do you think the problem is?

Thank you!

Comment: Currently having the same issue, can't either figure out why I'm getting the blank screen on mobile... I'm using the same quite basic example of Marzipano implementation for my needs, too.

Comment: Having the same problem but on the desktop.  Even using the demo, the viewer loads but the image is black.  I can still see the info targets and pan around but cannot see the image.  I've tried with Safari, Chrome, and firefox and have tried disabling security settings all to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Is the size of your canvas in the inspector set to 0 ?
If yes, you might want to trigger the resize event after a small delay. So Marzipano will recompute the size of the canvas to display.
I had the same issue, and this fixed it.
My guess is that when the marzipano element is initialized, the layout of the page isn't calculated yet.

Something like this:

```
scene.switchTo();
setTimeout(()=>{
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 60);
```

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Awesome tip, thanks. Same thing happens with Panolens, but I didn't think to try it here.